# ¿El atributo hidden de HTML serviría para ocultar datos sensibles sin que nadie los vea?

Tags: html, seguridad

En HTML tenemos el atributo global `hidden` que sirve para ocultar elementos en una página cualquiera.

La [documentación de MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Atributos_Globales/hidden) dice lo siguiente:

> El explorador no dibujará dichos elementos .

La afirmación es ambigua y confusa.

**¿Significa que un elemento que sea `hidden` no podrá verse de ninguna manera del lado del cliente**?

**¿O podrá verse por ejemplo examinando el código fuente de la página?**

La documentación no dice ni advierte nada al respecto, y uno podría estar guardando datos sensibles con un atributo `hidden` pensando que nadie podrá verlo.

Me gustaría saber si realmente el atributo `hidden` sirve para ocultar datos sensibles que no queremos que sean vistos bajo ningún concepto, por ejemplo una `API-KEY` o cosas de ese tipo.

Comment: Se seguirá viendo en la herramienta de desarrolladores

Comment: @Yikarus agradecería una respuesta con prueba y documentación si es posible. No comprendo cómo MDN no dice nada al respecto. Lo que se afirma de ese atributo es confuso. ¿Por qué no dicen que se seguirá viendo?

Comment: En realidad ni siquiera los input de tipo `password` son realmente seguros. Es cosa de editar su tipo a `text` en la consola para ver su contenido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para que el navegador puede mostrar cualquier documento HTML, tiene que tener acceso al mismo. Por tanto, todo lo que hayas incluido en el documento es accesible para el navegador y, por tanto para el usuario.

Puedes comprobarlo simplemente pulsando <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> en cualquier navegador, lo que te mostrará el código recibido. Por supuesto, mediante Javascript se pueden añadir o quitar elementos que no están presentes en el código HTML recibido, pero el estado actual de la página también puede ser accedido (y modificado) desde las herramientas para desarrolladores que todos los navegadores modernos incluyen y que se pueden activar pulsando <kbd>F12</kbd> o <kbd>Crtl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd>.

Cualquier medida de seguridad que se use para evitar el acceso de los usuarios a información reservada ha de tomarse siempre del lado del servidor. Cualquier medida realizada en el lado del cliente es siempre evitable y púramente cosmética.

¿Entonces, para qué sirve el `<input>` de tipo `hidden`? Pues para guardar información útil de una manera cómoda. Hay que recordar que el protocolo HTTP es *stateless*, es decir, no tiene memoria. Por tanto, o mantienes desde el lado del servidor una sesión con la información del usuario, u obligas al usuario a mandarte en cada petición todos los datos necesarios.

La sesión es tentadoramente fácil de usar, pero tiene una pega: si guardamos X cantidad de información sobre cada usuario, si tienes N usuarios con sesiones abiertas, necesitas NX espacio de memoria para guardar información. La alternativa sencilla es que cada usuario mantenga esa información desde el cliente. Y ahí entran los input hidden: si en un formulario guardas el ID del usuario en campo hidden, al enviar dicho formulario (al hacer una acción "submit"), dicho campo se enviará junto con cualquier otro campo visible.

Answer (score 2):

Sí se puede ver, y lo puedes comprobar viendo el código de [stackoverflow](https://es.stackoverflow.com)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

hidden se utiliza generalmente para almacenar valores de datos **NO SENSIBLES**, la documentación dice que no serán dibujados
                 en otras palabras es como si un elemento tuviera display:none, mas el elemento y su valor siempre se verá en el código fuente

Answer (score 2):

Siempre se puede ver ¿por qué? por que lo que hace el `hidden` es simplemente ocultarlo mas no lo elimina del DOM, algo así como un `display:none` en `css`, incluso al tener un `input` de tipo `hidden` se puede acceder a su valor por medio de `JavaScript` para enviar peticiones etc.

Es por todo esto que un dato sensible NUNCA podrá ocultarse en un `input` de ese tipo, incluso existe código `JavaScript` para bloquear el clic derecho en el sitio y que un usuario "no pueda acceder al inspector"...se puede bloquear el click, si !! pero al inspector se puede acceder por medio de atajos de teclado inclusive por medio del menú de herramientas de Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

Veamos: Suponiendo que quiera guardar un dato sensible como un ID:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Hidden</title>
 <span hidden="hidden">Id</span></head>
</head>
<body>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Ciertamente no lo muestra,pero,si accedemos desde un navegador los datos quedan expuestos al inspeccionar código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Consideraría que tiene que ver mas con la estética y presentación de una pagina, pero para mi gusto utilizaría mejor la propiedad `display` de `CSS`.

En cuanto a seguridad de datos siempre sera mejor que estén del lado del servidor, oculto a la vista del usuario.